# Which NFC tag will be suitable for my requirement

Tags: android, tags, hardware, nfc

I am currently working on restaurant interaction.
I require a URL and record to support AAR in my Android app.
Can anyone suggest me which tags will be suitable for this?
Please, mention the link where I can get the tag.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following webpage to determine the required size for an NFC-tag: http://nearfieldcommunication.com/developers/choosing-tags/

Because you want an URL and an AAR you should enter the wanted URL, remember the necessary amount of bytes and afterwards create an URL with the package name. Because an AAR is made out of the package name of your application and it is almost the same size in bytes as an URL add it to the amount of bytes necessary for the URL.

In this way you don't need to install the plugin and afterwards you have the option on selecting specific tags and you will get a list on were to order the NFC-tags.

Answer (score 0):

Use a short package identifier, then add the data you'd like in a minimal form, like an id (to which there is more information online). Try [this](http://code.google.com/p/nfc-eclipse-plugin/wiki/Tutorial) (shameless plug), the editor auto-computes the size for any NDEF message.